# Where is remember_me cookie checked in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication

When I login using the [remember_me](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users) feature in Laravel 5.8, a  remember_me token is stored in the users table and in the cookie. When a user opens the page with expired session, then at some place in Laravel the cookie value must be compared to the remember_token and re-login the user. But where exactly does this take place?

I checked `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` but could not find that anywhere. I need to catch this event, because I need to update the session on my Login-server using the refresh token.

Comment: On your env if your `SESSION_DRIVER=file` then its stored on server, if you make `SESSION_DRIVER=database` then it will store on your database

Comment: @EsTeAa thats right. But my question is not about where the session is stored, but where the cookie value is compared to the remember_me token inside the Laravel framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` in the `user()` method.

There is this code section:

```
// If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
// pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
// the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
$recaller = $this->recaller();

if (is_null($this->user) && ! is_null($recaller)) {
    $this->user = $this->userFromRecaller($recaller);

     if ($this->user) {
        $this->updateSession($this->user->getAuthIdentifier());

        $this->fireLoginEvent($this->user, true);
     }
}
```

The variable `$recaller` holds the cookie value.

The method `userFromRecaller` will try to retrieve user by Token:

```
protected function userFromRecaller($recaller)
{
    if (! $recaller->valid() || $this->recallAttempted) {
        return;
    }

    // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
    // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
    // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
    $this->recallAttempted = true;

    $this->viaRemember = ! is_null($user = $this->provider->retrieveByToken(
        $recaller->id(), $recaller->token()
    ));

    return $user;
}
```

From here you have to check which provider driver you have specifified in `config/auth.php` (eloquent or database), depending on that you can continue the path on the method `retrieveByToken` on EloquentUserProvider or DatabaseUserProvider.

For example, the EloquentUserProvider will compare the token value with the remembertoken of the model like this:

```
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
{
    $model = $this->createModel();

    $model = $model->where($model->getAuthIdentifierName(), $identifier)->first();

    if (! $model) {
        return null;
    }

    $rememberToken = $model->getRememberToken();

    return $rememberToken && hash_equals($rememberToken, $token) ? $model : null;
}
```

The method `getRememberToken()` is definied on the Users model via the `Authenticatable` trait.